# Different response for same API method

Tags: rest-assured, hamcrest

New to the RestAssured and just checking different ways of working with REST APIs. For testing I am using http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1. In this I am trying the GET employee method using RequestSpecification and groovy way but I am getting different response.

My short code is:

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1";
RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();
Response response = request.get("/employee/72100");
System.out.println(response.getBody().asString());

given().baseUri("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1").get("/employee/72100").then().log().body();
```

And output I am getting is:

```
{"id":"72100","employee_name":"mpr51_0280","employee_salary":"123","employee_age":"23","profile_image":""}
```

```
<html>
  <body>{"id":"72100","employee_name":"mpr51_0280","employee_salary":"123","employee_age":"23","profile_image":""}</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting why it is returning response with HTML tags. Can anyone explain or give hint to get same response as first call to get method.

NOTE: You may or may not get details for employeeID 72100
You can use any employee ID from response of:
http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the Body contains it .

You can use below statement if you need only the response

```
given().baseUri("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1").get("/employee/72100").then().log();
```

OR

```
Response resp = given().baseUri("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1").get("/employee/72100");
        System.out.println(resp.asString());
```